# React nested routes - undefined match

Tags: reactjs, api, router, nested-routes

First time using nested routes, so I am following this example as well as the article:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-routes-react-router-y5pt4?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js:2684-2693
https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-handle-nested-routes-in-react-router/

However, the data that I am fetching has a different structure compared to the example, like a collection of articles.
https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=test

What I am trying to do is to use the *pillarName* as the main navbar. The *sectionName* as the sub navbar, to map articles that belong to each subcategory.

The problem is that when I console.log(":infoSectionName", match) the WorldNews component, I get an *undefined* and so I can't map individual articles.

Source Code : https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-silence-g6q66?file=/src/App.js:5802-5811

I would really appreciate your advice.

Comment: your demo actually works

Comment: Yes, I have updated the demo. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining route like this:

```
<Route path={`${match.path}/:infoSectionName`} component={WorldNews} />
```